# Timelion series from cumulative sum of array length

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5, timelion

I have documents, that look similar to below:

```
{
    dateTime: /* My time field */,
    message: {
        users: ['1', '2']
    },
    messageType: 'test'
}
```

I'd like to construct a timelion series chart that shows me a cumulative sum of the count of the array `message.users`. My first inkling was to create a script:

```
if(doc.containsKey('message.users')) {
    return doc['message.users'].length;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

From what I could tell, `doc.containsKey('message.users')` always was false, which tells me that it may not have been indexed correctly. I've tried numerous Timelion, all to no avail:

```
.es(index=logstash-*,timefield='dateTime',q='messageType:UserList').label('Users Online')
```

I index my document through the c# NEST api like so:

```
elasticClient.Index(
    new
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Now,
        Message = evt.EventArgs.Message,
    },
    idx => idx.Index($"logstash-{evt.MessageCode}"));
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your `message.users` field?

Comment: Another good practice is to simply create another field at indexing time called `userCount` which contains the number of users in your `message.users` array.

Comment: @Val, sorry new to elasticsearch. I just used the C# Nest API, and I've updated my answer with how I'm indexing the document.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to add another field called `userCount` to your documents so you don't need to mess with scripting (+ it'll be more performant).

So your documents should look like this:

```
{
    dateTime: /* My time field */,
    message: {
        users: ['1', '2']
    },
    userCount: 2,                  <--- add this field
    messageType: 'test'
}
```

Solution 1:

You'd need to change your code a tiny bit to this:

```
elasticClient.Index(
    new
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Now,
        Message = evt.EventArgs.Message,
        UserCount = evt.EventArgs.Message.Users.Length
    },
    idx => idx.Index($"logstash-{evt.MessageCode}"));
```

Solution 2:

If you're using ES 5, you can leverage the [Ingest API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) in order to create a pipeline that will automatically add that `userCount` field for you. You don't have to change anything in your code.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/user-count-pipeline
{
  "description" : "Creates a new userCount field",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "ctx.userCount = ctx.message?.users?.size() ?: 0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, in Timelion, it'll be very easy to chart what you need using `metric='sum:userCount'` to sum the `userCount` values and the `cusum()` function to get the cumulative sum of the `userCount`over time. The whole expression would look like this:

```
.es(index=logstash-*,timefield='dateTime',q='messageType:UserList',metric='sum:userCount').label('Users Online').cusum()
```

Using a few sample documents, the time series looks like this, which seems to be what you're looking for.

[image: Users online]

Comment: Is it possible to do it without creating the additional field `UserCount`?

Comment: It would be cool if it was possible to define a scripted field (e.g. `return params['_source'].message.users.size()`) inside Kibana and then use it in Timelion, but unfortunately [it is not supported yet](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/9022).

Comment: What about indexing the user array, and using a function to get the size of the users array?

Comment: If you're using ES 5, I have another solution. See my updated answer.